# MySQL concatenate values from one table into a record of another

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (many to many relationship): `items`, `items_to_tags`, and `tags`. The `items` and `tags` tables have a unique ID column, and the `items_to_tags` table has columns `item_id` and `tag_id`. Is there a way to select all results from the `items` and `tags` tables, but with all results merged into the same record?

For instance, if I have this data:

- `items`:

  ```
  id     name
  1      'item1'
  2      'item2'
  ```
- `tags`:

  ```
  id     name
  1      'tag1'
  2      'tag2'
  3      'tag3'
  ```
- `items_to_tags`:

  ```
  item_id    tag_id
  1          1
  1          2
  1          3
  2          3
  ```

The result of the query should be:

```
item_id   item_name   tags
1         'item1'     'tag1,tag2,tag3'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the MySQL [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select i.id,
  i.name,
  group_concat(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') tags
from items i
left join items_to_tags it
  on i.id = it.item_id
left join tags t
  on it.tag_id = t.id
group by i.id, i.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dca9d/9)

Result:

```
| ID |  NAME |             TAGS |
---------------------------------
|  1 | item1 | tag1, tag2, tag3 |
|  2 | item2 |             tag3 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).